# primefaces validation doesn't work when there is an input in the autocomplete field

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a jsf form and it includes p:autoCompelete fields. Here you are;

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!--    DPR FORM   -->

            <p:panel header="Delivery Problem Report">

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <p:outputLabel value="To (Supplier) :" for="supplierAuto" />
                    <p:autoComplete id="supplierAuto"  dropdown="true" value="#{dprCreate.supplierCode}"
                    completeMethod="#{dprCreate.completeSupplier}"
                    var="supplier" itemLabel="#{supplier.supplierName}" itemValue="#{supplier.supplierCode}" 
                    scrollHeight="250" required="true" />

                    <h:outputText value="DPR Date: *" style="font-size: small" />
                    <p:calendar id="dprDate" value="#{dprCreate.dprDate}" 
                        pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="en" title="Begin Date" />

                    <h:outputText value="Invoice No:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{dprCreate.invoiceNo}" >
                    </p:inputText>

                    <h:outputText value="Waybill No:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{dprCreate.waybill}" >
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Part Number:" for="PartNumberAuto" />
                    <p:autoComplete id="PartNumberAuto"  dropdown="true" value="#{dprCreate.partNumber}"
                    completeMethod="#{dprCreate.completePartNumbers}"
                    var="partNumber" itemLabel="#{partNumber.partNumber}" itemValue="#{partNumber.partNumber}" 
                    scrollHeight="250" required="true" />


                    <h:outputText value="Color Code:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{dprCreate.color}" >
                    </p:inputText>

                    <h:outputText value="Quantity:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{dprCreate.quantity}" >
                    </p:inputText>



                    <p:outputLabel value="Problem Type:" for="ProblemAuto" />

                    <p:autoComplete id="ProblemAuto"   value="#{dprCreate.problemId}"
                    completeMethod="#{dprCreate.completeProblems}" dropdown="true"
                    var="problem" itemLabel="#{problem.problemName}" itemValue="#{problem.problemId}" 
                    scrollHeight="250" required="true"/>


        <p:commandButton action="#{dprCreate.save}" value="Save" update="form1" ajax="false" style="width:150px" />
        <p:button outcome="/dpr/list" value="See All DPR" style="width:150px"/> 
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>
            </h:form>
```

There are 3 validations in the form. They are "required=true". Also, they are in the p:autocomplete fields.

So, the issue is that when I click the 'save button' with no input, validation works fine.
However, when I put an input in only one p:autocomplete field then click the 'save' button, primefaces validation doesn't work and I get java error. I mean I expect to get front end validation error because of other two empty required field. But the system passes the front-end validation and it reach my back end code.

Here is my java bean code.

```
package com.honda.srm.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import com.honda.srm.dao.ConnectionManager;
import com.honda.srm.model.Authentication;
import com.honda.srm.dao.PartNumberDAO;
import com.honda.srm.dao.ProblemDAO;
import com.honda.srm.dao.DprDAO;
import com.honda.srm.model.PartNumber;
import com.honda.srm.model.Problem;
import com.honda.srm.model.Dpr;
import com.honda.srm.model.Supplier;
import com.honda.srm.model.User;
import com.honda.srm.controller.SendEmail;
import com.honda.srm.dao.SupplierDAO;
import com.honda.util.FacesUtil;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

@ManagedBean(name = "dprCreate")
@ViewScoped
public class DprCreate implements Serializable {

    private String formId;
    private String to;
    private Date dprDate = new Date();
    private Date formDate = new Date();
    private String invoiceNo;
    private String waybill;
    private String partNumber;
    private String color;
    private Integer quantity;
    private String supplierCode;
    private List<Problem> problems;
    private List<Supplier> suppliers;
    private List<Dpr> unreportedDprs;
    private List<Dpr> dprsOfSupplier;
    private Integer problemId;
    private Integer statusId;
    private String filledBy;
    public Dpr dpr = new Dpr();
    private User user;
    public String username;
    private List<Supplier> selectedSuppliers;


    public DprCreate() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Authentication auth = (Authentication) FacesUtil
                .getSessionAttribute("auth");
        user = auth.getUser();
        username=user.getUsername();
        unreportedDprs = new DprDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection())
                .getunreportedDprs();

        dprsOfSupplier = new DprDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection())
        .getDprsOfSupplier(username);

        suppliers = new SupplierDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection())
        .getSuppliers();

    }

    public List<Supplier> completeSupplier(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        List<Supplier> allSuppliers = new SupplierDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection())
        .getSuppliers();
        List<Supplier> filteredSuppliers = new ArrayList<Supplier>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allSuppliers.size(); i++) {
            Supplier supplier = allSuppliers.get(i);
            if(supplier.getSupplierName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
                filteredSuppliers.add(supplier);
            }
        }

        return filteredSuppliers;
    }
    public List<Problem> completeProblems(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        List<Problem> allProblems = new ProblemDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection())
        .getAllProblems();
        List<Problem> filteredProblems = new ArrayList<Problem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allProblems.size(); i++) {
            Problem problem = allProblems.get(i);
            if(problem.getProblemName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
                filteredProblems.add(problem);
            }
        }

        return filteredProblems;
    }

    public List<PartNumber> completePartNumbers(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        List<PartNumber> allPartNumber = new PartNumberDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection())
        .getPartNumbers();
        List<PartNumber> filteredPartNumbers = new ArrayList<PartNumber>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allPartNumber.size(); i++) {
            PartNumber partNumber = allPartNumber.get(i);
            if(partNumber.getPartNumber().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
                filteredPartNumbers.add(partNumber);
            }
        }  
        return filteredPartNumbers;
    }

    private String createFormNumber()
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String query = " CALL TESTAE.FORMSEQR (?)";
        CallableStatement cstmt = ConnectionManager.getCallableStatement(query);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.execute();
        String as400formid = cstmt.getString(1);
        cstmt.close();
        return as400formid;
    }

    public String save() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ParseException, MessagingException, IOException {
        DprDAO dprDAO = new DprDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection());

        dpr.setFormId(createFormNumber()); 
        dpr.setTo(supplierCode);
        dpr.setDprDate(dprDate);

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date today = new Date();
        formDate = formatter.parse(formatter.format(today));

        dpr.setFormDate(formDate);
        dpr.setInvoiceNo(invoiceNo);
        dpr.setWaybill(waybill);
        dpr.setPartNumber(partNumber);
        dpr.setColor(color);
        dpr.setQuantity(quantity);
        dpr.setProblemId(problemId);
        dpr.setStatusId(1);
        dpr.setFilledBy(username);  
        dprDAO.insertHeader(dpr);

        SendEmail.main(dpr.getFormId(), dpr.getTo(), dpr.getStatusId());

        return "/dpr/create?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public List<Supplier> getSuppliers() {
        return suppliers;
    }

    public void setSuppliers(List<Supplier> suppliers) {
        this.suppliers = suppliers;
    }
    public String getSupplierCode() {
        return supplierCode;
    }

    public void setSupplierCode(String supplierCode) {
        this.supplierCode = supplierCode;
    }

    public String getFormId() {
        return formId;
    }

    public void setFormId(String formId) {
        this.formId = formId;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public Dpr getDpr() {
        return dpr;
    }

    public void setDpr(Dpr dpr) {
        this.dpr = dpr;
    }

    public Date getDprDate() {
        return dprDate;
    }


    public void setDprDate(Date dprDate) {
        this.dprDate = dprDate;
    }


    public String getInvoiceNo() {
        return invoiceNo;
    }


    public void setInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo) {
        this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }


    public String getWaybill() {
        return waybill;
    }


    public void setWaybill(String waybill) {
        this.waybill = waybill;
    }


    public String getPartNumber() {
        return partNumber;
    }


    public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
    }


    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }


    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }


    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }


    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


    public List<Problem> getProblems() {
        return problems;
    }


    public void setProblems(List<Problem> problems) {
        this.problems = problems;
    }   

    public Integer getProblemId() {
        return problemId;
    }

    public void setProblemId(Integer problemId) {
        this.problemId = problemId;
    }

    public Integer getStatusId() {
        return statusId;
    }

    public void setStatusId(Integer statusId) {
        this.statusId = statusId;
    }

    public String getFilledBy() {
        return filledBy;
    }

    public void setFilledBy(String filledBy) {
        this.filledBy = filledBy;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Dpr> getUnreportedDprs() {
        return unreportedDprs;
    }

    public void setUnreportedDprs(List<Dpr> unreportedDprs) {
        this.unreportedDprs = unreportedDprs;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Date getFormDate() {
        return formDate;
    }

    public void setFormDate(Date formDate) {
        this.formDate = formDate;
    }

    public List<Dpr> getDprsOfSupplier() {
        return dprsOfSupplier;
    }

    public void setDprsOfSupplier(List<Dpr> dprsOfSupplier) {
        this.dprsOfSupplier = dprsOfSupplier;
    }

    public List<Supplier> getSelectedSuppliers() {
        return selectedSuppliers;
    }

    public void setSelectedSuppliers(List<Supplier> selectedSuppliers) {
        this.selectedSuppliers = selectedSuppliers;
    }


}
```

The back end error;

```
root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /dpr/create.xhtml @27,58 itemLabel="#{supplier.supplierName}": Property 'supplierName' not found on type java.lang.String
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.getItemLabel(AutoComplete.java:148)
    org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeInput(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:190)
    org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSingleMarkup(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:147)
    org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeMarkup(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:130)
    org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:108)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:81)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:68)
    org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
    org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
    org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.honda.service.UTF8EncodingFilter.doFilter(UTF8EncodingFilter.java:30)
```

Do you have any idea?

PS: I use jsf 2.2, primafaces 5.0, Eclipse Luna. Wondows 7.

Thank you all!

Good day.

Comment: Can you post the 'java error' you get ?

Comment: I guess, Java error is not important for this case. So, I didnt post it here. My problem is that why does not primafaces validation work on all field which is defined required? Still, I can share the backend error.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is at the mapping autocompletes values.
For exemple for the first autocomplete, the value is mapped with "#{dprCreate.supplierCode}" that has the type String --> you must declare an object of type "Supplier" in your managedBean (do not forget to instantiate him)

```
private Supplier supplier
```

and map the value with this object

```
<p:autoComplete id="supplierAuto"  dropdown="true" value="#{dprCreate.supplier}"
                completeMethod="#{dprCreate.completeSupplier}"
                var="supplier" itemLabel="#{supplier.supplierName}" itemValue="#{supplier}" 
                scrollHeight="250" required="true" />
```

and the same for the other autocompletes

Comment: When I try this, primefaces autocomplete fails. When I start to write something in the autocomplete field, the supplier list is not seen.

Comment: I think the problem is about primefaces validation. why does not primafaces validation work on all field which is defined required? I do not understand where I am wrong.